# I want to pass test_var in the echo command of pass_flag

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I'm parsing an XML file `users.xml` and I want to pass `$3` which holds the password value to `trial.sh`.
The XML file looks like this:

```
<Users>
<user>
<name>Veera</name>
<password>!#!veera@nbs</password>
</user>
</Users>
```

---

```
  awk '
    BEGIN { FS = "[<|>]" }
    {
           if ($2 == "password") 
           {
               if($3=="!#!veera@nbs")
                {
                   encrypted="'"`sh test.sh $3`"'" 
                   sub($3,encrypted)
                }
           }
            print
    }
    ' users.xml > users2.xml
```

The XML file has element `password` and `$3` holds the new password which I want to pass to `trial.sh` that encrypts the `$3` (`!#!veera@nbs`) and returns the result which will be stored in an `awk` variable encrypted and replaces the existing value.

Comment: Hi Ed thanks for the help.. I have edited it..

Comment: Hey Ed, I hope u can help me now

Comment: You are going to run into problems if someone uses either `<` or `>` in their password (or `|` — in a character class, you don't need an explicit 'or' operation).  It's always fun finding out which sites won't let you use angle brackets.  I also observe that the title mentions `echo` and `test_var`, neither of which appears in the body of the question.  That's confusing.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, can you recommend some tips for xml parsing

Comment: I have tried with many Jonathan but most dint suit to my requirement.. can u suggest some links

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'</?password>' 'NF>1{print $2}' file
!#!veera@nbs
```

so:

```
test.sh "$(awk -F'</?password>' 'NF>1{print $2}' file)"
```

The above assumes your files are always as well formed as your sample shows and don't have, for example, the password value on a different line from the tags.